# AWK Beginner Bar Graph/Histogram

Tags: linux, unix, awk, terminal

I've been assigned this prompt as legitimately my first real `awk` program and I'm not even sure where to start. Any help to get started would be greatly appreciated.

Write an awk program called `hist.awk` that reads a file of numbers and prints a histogram of occurrences. For the input shown below:

```
1
4
5
0
2
4
6
8
1
3
2
4
6
7
2
3
3
4
4
```

The output will be:

```
0:        1 ***
1:        2 ******
2:        3 ********
3:        3 ********
4:        5 **************
5:        1 ***
6:        2 ******
7:        1 ***
8:        1 ***
```

The first column contains the numbers from the file. The second contains the number of times that number occurred. The graph shows the percentage of the total, scaled to 50, so 50 asterisks indicates 100%, 25 asterisks indicates 50%, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please wrap your samples up in CODE TAGS.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you(though I am still not sure about your `*` printing in output).

```
awk 'function astrick_printing(var){;num=val=count="";count=((var*100)/50);while(++num<=count){val=val "*"};return val;} {a[$0]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i],astrick_printing(a[i])}}'  Input_file | sort
```

Adding non one liner form of above solution too now:

```
awk '
function astrick_printing(var){
  num=val=count="";
  count=((var*100)/50);
  while(++num<=count){
    val=val "*"};
  return val
}
{
  a[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i,a[i],astrick_printing(a[i])}
}
'  Input_file | sort
```

Output will be as follows:

```
0 1 **
1 2 ****
2 3 ******
3 3 ******
4 5 **********
5 1 **
6 2 ****
7 1 **
8 1 **
```

Answer (score 3):

The following `awk` line does what is requested:

- it does a propper rounding of the count to get the correct stars (4.5 stars => 5 stars, 4.2 stars => 4 stars)
- It has a string of 50 `*` in memory and only prints the part needed. It does this with the format specifier `.ws` where `w` is replaced by `int(a[i]*50/c+0.5)`.
- It keeps track of the smallest and biggest number accounted. Any number not appearing in the range will be printed with 0 stars.

The script reads:

```
awk 'BEGIN{imin=+999999;imax=-99999;
           stars="**************************************************"
     }
     {a[$1]++;imin=$i<imin?$i:imin; imax=$i>imax?$i:imax}
     END{ for(i=imin;i<=imax;i++) 
             printf "%3d: %-4d %.*s\n",i,a[i],int(a[i]*50/NR+0.5),stars    
     }' file.txt
```

and outputs:

```
  0: 1    ***
  1: 2    *****
  2: 3    ********
  3: 3    ********
  4: 5    *************
  5: 1    ***
  6: 2    *****
  7: 1    ***
  8: 1    ***
```

Everything is based on [`printf` format modifiers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html). The format to be printed reads

```
%3d: %-4d %.*s\n
```

Which reads:

- (`%3d`) print an integer with width of 3
- (`-4d`) print an integer with width of 4 left justified
- (`%.*s`) is a variant of `%.ws`, stating print the first `w` characters of a string. The value of `w` (represented by `*`) is picked up from the argument list.

If you do not care about numbers which do not appear in your list (eg. your file has `10` but not `9` then the above will have a line `9: 0` as output. If you do not care about this, then you can do :

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
            stars="**************************************************" }
     {a[$1]++}
     END{ for(i in a) 
              printf "%3d: %-4d %.*s\n",i,a[i],int(a[i]*50/NR+0.5),stars
     }' file.txt
```

The `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` is needed to ensure an ordered traversing of the indices of `a`. This however is a [`gawk` extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html).

Comment: You can use `printf("%3d: %-4d %.*s\n",i,a[i],a[i]*50/NR,"********")`

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was not sure what was more confusing, the `*` or injecting `a[i]` directly.

Comment: `%.*s` , no of chars, and then char to be printed ++

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a)printf("%3d: %-4d %.*s\n",i,a[i],a[i]*50/NR,"************************") | "sort"}' file`

Comment: @AkshayHegde updated, and added the `for(i in a)`. Note that this does not show empty bins. The sort is removed with `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"`

Comment: Yes `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` works with Gawk

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
 $ awk '{a[$1]++; c++} 
     END{for(k in a) 
           {s=sprintf("%*s",a[k]*50/c,FS); 
            gsub(FS,"*",s); 
            print k":", a[k], s}}' file


0: 1 **
1: 2 *****
2: 3 *******
3: 3 *******
4: 5 *************
5: 1 **
6: 2 *****
7: 1 **
8: 1 **
```